# Tab pane active gone when navbar menu clicked

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I have Navbar menu and tab pane bootstrap like this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><?php echo $surname; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Profile</a></li>
               <li><a href=""><span class="fa fa-unlock"></span> Change Password</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Page 1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('logout'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

when ever i click the tab pane the domain will change like
/home#dashboard or /home#task

but when i clicked the drop down menu in navbar, the tab active pane will gone and the there is no tab pane where active. while i still want to see the content of active tab pane. I do know that the `<a href="#">` that make the tab active pane gone when the dropdown were clicked. 
how do i fixed this to prevent the clicked dropdwon menu navbar will not change the active tab pane ?

Reference would be welcome, and thanks

**Using href element**

[image]

**Using button element**
[image]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><?php echo $surname; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Profile</a></li>
               <li><a href=""><span class="fa fa-unlock"></span> Change Password</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Page 1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('logout'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not a real solution, but it looks like [you could use a `button` dropdown](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#single-button-dropdowns) in order to avoid the problem

Comment: but it's contradicted with my <li> tag, while the element is <div> @Aaron
since it was navbar...

Comment: it works, but the css broken

Comment: Not sure I understood your first comment, but it's the dropdown's `<a>` tag(s?) that should be changed into `<button>`. Note that I haven't coded any HTML/JS in a long time and I'm still pretty sure it's a mediocre solution : there should be a way to make multiple UI components of bootstrap-3 cohabit that doesn't force one of their specific implementations (unless this was documented, but I didn't see it while reading bootstrap-3's dropdown documentation)

Comment: sorry about my first comment, 
Perhaps, i should wait for another reference. Yours is good, but there is an issue with the css, since i am not so advanced in css

Comment: Yeah, you probably should unless you know much better than I do what you're doing ;) It's weird that the `button` CSS is broken though, if you correctly integrate bootstrap's CSS it should provide the same styling for the button as to the link. From the linked documentation's examples both tags seem to need the exact same attributes, so I don't see any obvious mistake you could have made.

Comment: @Aaron i updated my question with an image, please take a look

Comment: Sorry, I'm on a network that blocks `*.imgur.com`, can't help you right now. Another suggestion though : have you tried keeping the `<a>` tags but removing their `href` attribute? I wouldn't be surprised if they were kept for older browser compatibility, since bootstrap's JS should in general handle the dropdown toggle through the onclick event with classes or data attributes. Otherwise I'll see what I can do when I'm back at home (in ~1h). If you could provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the problem by then it would be great :)

Comment: Yes,  i have removed the `href` and its finally works, but the url looks ugly like `home#null`, and then when i am trying to hover the `nav` menu, the pointer didnt change to "hand" pointer. I used css for change the pointer on hover with `cursor:pointer` however, it's the best way i can do, and thanks again for the suggest @Aaron

Comment: how do i use jsfiddle on stackoverflow ?

Comment: I'm surprised it even works if the url's hash is changed : I'm wondering why `null` would work better than an empty hash. For JSFiddle you save it once you've succesfully reproduced your problem then you share the resulting url in here :)

Comment: @Aaron i have added some snippet please check it out, and in this snippet.. it works perfectly... i dunno why

Comment: I thought it was because of the way it was included in SO's snippets, but I've pasted the code in an HTML page of my own and it works just as well (clicking the navbar or the dropdown don't change the URL's hash). I guess that's because of some JS ; are you sure it is correctly included in your page, and that there's no error displayed to the console at load or on click?

Comment: Same with your initial code actually, once I've added the head you have in your snippet. But maybe it only reproduces on specific browsers? (I'm on an up-to-date Chrome under Windows 7 here)